# Using PC audio to listen to electrical noise on power line?

Tags: filter, noise, computers, interference

I have done a bit of research on digital filtering and I was wondering if it would be possible to use the audio hardware of my computer tu listen to the electrical noise on my powerline ? If it is possible, does anyone have an idea of how to proceed ?

I was thinking I could maybe plug a cable linked to the house line into the microphone input channel of the computer. But I don't know how I would have to proceed to get it to work... I can imagine the computer not liking the 240V straight from the mains very much.

The reason why I'm interested in this is to be able to monitor the activity of some of the appliances around the house based on the conducted interference they cause on the house power line. From what I have read I expect the frequencies of the interferences to be around 40 to 80 kHz.

Comment: Power lines have long been used to transmit information. The technology is known as power-line communication (PLC) power-line carrier, power-line digital subscriber line (PDSL), mains communication, power-line telecommunications, or power-line networking (PLN). If you find information on that technology, you will find how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

NEVER make a straight connection between mains power and any other device unless you 100% know what you're doing. Since you have to ask, I assume you lack the knowledge to work with mains voltage directly.

Indeed computers do not like straight connections to mains but computers that are blown up can be replaced. However, humans can die when connected to mains.

You will need to use a mains transformer, if you have an old mains adapter that supplies an AC voltage like 12V AC, this could be used safely. Adapters that output a DC voltage are NOT suitable for what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am indeed looking to further my knowledge before even building and testing anything. Once I've got something working on paper I'll make sure I get it check by someone.

Comment: I would look at integrating an opto-isolator into your design and completely isolating the two halves of circuit (including grounds, etc). You'll need a step-down transformer and a quick-acting overvoltage protection as well, probably on the secondary side. You'll then need to deal with the one-sidedness of opto-isolators, which is the old Class A/B amp problem, maybe by introducing a DC shift.

Comment: Its probably worth noting that once you have sufficiently isolated yourself and your PC from the mains voltage, the noise you're trying to listen to on the mains may have been filtered out anyway by the isolation transformer and etc.

Comment: @FakeMoustache "You will need to use a mains transformer, if you have an old mains adapter that supplies an AC voltage like 12V AC, this could be used safely."

This is distinctly wrong. if you put 120V or even 12V into your sound card you WILL DESTROY IT and probably your computer. You would need to bring it down to [line level] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) AND any transformer you use designed for power is going to filter out almost all noise anyway.

Comment: @Sam, I forgot to mention that the 12V needs to be attenuated, thought it was obvious. Also 12 V AC should not destroy a properly designed soundcard as these usually have some input resistance and overvoltage protection, if not on the PCB then the ESD protection diodes on any chip will take care of this. Please explain why a transformer would filter out all noise, normally transformers don't (upto a certain frequency). Did you know that there are sound distribution systems that use transformers, these let all audio signals pass without filtering.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Transformers commericaly avalible for power appications are usually in the high milihenry impedances, meaning they are going to act as a low pass filter. Most "noise" on a power line is either impulses (infinite frequency) or data carrying (very high frequency) so, yeah a transformer is going to filter the noise.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your pc audio card is only going to pick up 20kHz and below, the only "noise" you are going to see in that frequency range (20000-1Hz) is likly to be the 60Hz of the power itself. Second "noise" is only interesting if you have an antenna that receives it, and you need to understand not only the freqency characteristics of the antenna but also any directonality to that antenna.

Comment: Hmm, noise only comes in via an antenna ? Obviously you have never heard of resistive coupling, coupling via ground, magnetic coupling ?

Comment: Or any noise from source

Comment: @FakeMoustache, any device that is suceptable to resitive coupling is going to have in input filter, I'm not sure what you mean by "coupling via ground" but I'm guessing you mean ground bounce, which a computer that is on the same ground isn't gong to be able to measure, and magenetic coupiling IS antenna coupling.

Comment: @MdxBhmt What? your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Like imperfections of the signal that comes from the source itself.  No system is perfect, and any imperfection may be labeled as noise when not specified.